# Call parse.com job from javascript using REST API

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform, appcelerator

As the title says, I'm trying to run a job on parse.com from javascript (specifically an Appcelerator Android app) using the REST API.  I'm using REST because this is just for diagnostics and I don't want to deal with trying to get the parse.com javascript API working in Appcelerator.  The problem is I cannot get authenticated.  If I don't pass in the authentication headers, I get the appropriate 401 authentication error, but if I do set them, I get "BAD REQUEST".  I have gotten it working via cURL, so the URL is right, and parse responds to the call as expected.  Here's my code:

```
var url = "https://api.parse.com/1/jobs/sendMail";

    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
         // function called when the response data is available
         onload : function(e) {
             Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
             alert("Received text: " + this.responseText);
         },
         // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
         onerror : function(e) {
             Ti.API.debug(e.error);
             alert(e.error);
         },
         timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
     });

     var param = {"text":msg};

     // Prepare the connection.
     var auth = {"app":"sTnsthoeunotreallymyappIDbutabunchofcharactersESnecu","key":"8ll5thisisntreallymykeyeitherhMKqkYG"};
     client.open("POST", url);

     client.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id",auth.app);
     client.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key",auth.key);

     client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

     // Send the request.
     client.send(param);
```

Here is the request and response:

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/jobs/sendMail HTTP/1.1
X-Parse-Application-Id: myappid
User-Agent: 
X-Parse-REST-API-Key: myrestapikey
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 0
Host: api.parse.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 22 Feb 2015 04:36:11 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Set-Cookie: _parse_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlMTY4MzY0NTZlOWQ3ZGRjZDJkOWQwMjA4MWZjNWViMTY%3D--ffc760efbe32aa80a5e6d369606361413433fa72; domain=.parse.com; path=/; expires=Tue, 24-Mar-2015 04:36:11 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
Status: 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Parse"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Runtime: 0.018320
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Content-Length: 24
Connection: keep-alive

{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

Comment: You could try relaying your request through Runscope and then do the same with cUrl and then use Runscope to do a side by side comparison to try and identify why it's not working in your Android app.

Comment: Clients may add other default headers. U will need to turn on logging ( Wire & headers ) or look at server log to see exactly what's being sent . same headers n wire as curl and you will get same results

Comment: I added the request and response to the question.  I used Fiddler to get that - seems simpler than Runscope.  However, when I use cURL (or ping) Fiddler doesn't show anything, so I am not sure what the differences are.  I've installed the cURL client on Windows 7 - any idea why Fiddler wouldn't show me that traffic?  I haven't found any answers with a bit of searching but I will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering background jobs via the REST-API requires using the Master-Key, not the REST-API key.

https://parse.com/docs/rest#backgroundjobs

Comment: Good catch, but I changed it to set the header "X-Parse-Master-Key" with the master key, and still get "Bad request".  Note that this is different from setting no authentication headers, when I get "Unauthorized".  So it appears rather than rejecting the credentials as incorrect, it's saying there is something malformed.

Comment: Hm, have you tried starting the job directly via the REST-API (using curl). From what you posted, there is no data sent to the API (Content-Length: 0), maybe somethings up there? If you can share the code for the job (simply remove all confidential parts) I can set it up in one of my apps to debug it.

Comment: It works fine from cURL.  I noticed that content length 0 as well, and there's also no user agent, but I don't know if either of those is the problem.  I don't think what the job does really matters - it's not even being run.  The issue is with getting a correct request from this mobile app.  If you happen to have any familiarity with Appcelerator, calling a parse job from there might shed some light. But I don't think there's much crossover between parse.com and Appcelerator.  BTW I was also trying to call mailgun directly to send an email and that gave me the same error.  Any clues there?

Comment: One thing that's confusing me about this is I can't capture the cURL traffic.  I've tried Fiddler, Charles, and MS Message Analyzer, and when I run the cURL command I see nothing going to parse.com in the traffic analyzers.